# jqploy not generatig horizontal bar chart if y-axix is string

Tags: jqplot

I need to generate a horizontal bar chart like given code but with Y-axis as some string not numbers.
What are the changes I need to do to this code for my work. It is working fine with numbers from 1-4 but once I put some string in place of numbers for Y-Axis, graph is not getting plotted.

My Code:

```
 plot4 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[[2,1], [6,2], [7,3], [10,4]], [[7,1], [5,2],[3,3],[2,4]]], {
            stackSeries: true,
            captureRightClick: true,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                shadowAngle: 135,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                    highlightMouseDown: true   
                },
                pointLabels: {show: true}
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                location: 'e',
                placement: 'outside'
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        });
```

I need to plot plot4:

> $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[[2,'a'], [6,'b'], [7,'c'], [10,'d']], [[7,'a'],
>   [5,'b'],[3,'c'],[2,'d']]], {

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use for this are the so called "ticks".

You want the data in the plot to stay the same, however you want to edit the yaxis options:

```
var ticks = ['axis1', 'axis2', 'axis3']; //String array for each axis

axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                }
}
```

Here a list of the full option list: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html

Hope this was usefull :)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me.Now My charts are working accordingly.

Comment: Glad i could help :) I know how hard it is to find a specific option for jQplot ^^ Don't forget to accept my answer :)